# Excel vba macro to delete rows in one sheet that do no match those in another using auto filter via input box

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter, inputbox

this is my first post, I am and novice user and would really like some help. I have been searching for a week to no avail. I have 2 Sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2) with a small macro assigned to delete any rows in Sheet1 which do not match those in Sheet2. I am also using a InputBox to capture the user defined criteria based on field 4, which works great and filters correctly. My problem is related to the second part as the deletion is performed for matches across the whole of Sheet1 (ignoring the filter). What I want is for the deletion to occur only on those rows filtered by by the user. Any help would be gratefully received, if you could annotate your answers that would be helpful and apologies if I am making rookie mistakes.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    'Deletes rows where one cell does not meet criteria

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim criteria As String
    Dim found As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Area As String
    Dim Data As Variant

    'Auto filters by user selection
    Area = InputBox("Enter your required Building(s) - comma separated")

    If InStr(1, Area, ",") > 0 Then
        Data = Split(Area, ",")
        Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Trim(Data(0)),     Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=Trim(Data(1))
    Else
        Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Area
    End If

    'Deletes all rows from Sheet1 that do not match
    For i = 2 To 100
       criteria = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value

       On Error Resume Next

       Set found = ws2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=criteria, LookAt:=xlWhole)

       On Error GoTo 0

       If found Is Nothing Then
         ws1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete

         i = i - 1
       End If

       Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)
The code checks if the row is hidden and only deletes the row if it isn't.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

'Deletes rows where one cell does not meet criteria

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim criteria As String

Dim found As Range

Dim i As Long

Dim Area As String

Dim Data As Variant

'Auto filters by user selection

Area = InputBox("Enter your required Building(s) - comma separated")

If InStr(1, Area, ",") > 0 Then

Data = Split(Area, ",")

Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Trim(Data(0)), Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=Trim(Data(1))

Else

Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Area

End If

'Deletes all rows from Sheet1 that do not match

For i = 2 To 100

criteria = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value

On Error Resume Next

Set found = ws2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=criteria, LookAt:=xlWhole)

On Error GoTo 0

If found Is Nothing And ws1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then ' Checks if the row is hidden
 ws1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete

 i = i - 1

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to help - consider accepting my answer if you feel it's the answer you were looking for :)